# Output Json Arrays with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jquery

I am really new to Javascript and Json and need help with the following. This is some json data:

```
"genres": [

 {
    "id": 28,
    "name": "Action"
 },
 {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "Drama"
 },
 {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Fantasy"
 },
 {
    "id": 36,
    "name": "History"
 }

],
```

Now I would like to output all names of genres

I'm working with jquery mobile and ajax to retrieve json data. Inside my function it looks sth like this:

```
var genres = results.genres[0].name;
$('#tmdbInfo2').html('<br>Genres: ' +genres);
```

In this example the first element of genres will we shown (Action), but not all.
The output should be: Action, Drama, Fantasy, History.
Sometimes the number of elements of genres varies..

Please help me, its very confusing for me O_o

Comment: I am sorry to say that, but you should have simply googled that. Or open up a basic tutorial on Javascript arrays.

Comment: I already did, believe me. I'm not a programmer. I found many examples, but couldn't transfer this to my problem.

Comment: Nobody is born as a programmer. If you want to do programming, well, you have no other chance but to learn it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to iterate:

```
results.genres.forEach(function(genre) {
    console.log(genre.name);
});
```

For what you're trying to do:

```
$('#tmdbInfo2').html(
    'Genres: ' + results.genres.map(function(genre) {
        return genre.name;
    }).join(', ')
);
```

Comment: Thank you so far. But how do would you save the results in a variable and output each item with html? I know this is all basic :p

Comment: You will need a `.get()` also before the `.join()`, `.map()` returns a jQuery-wrapped array. Also, I find your example very confusing for a beginner, but it's nice :).

Comment: @bažmegakap: Why would `Array.prototype.map` return a jQuery-wrapped array?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! You saved me many hours of work, which I currently don't have. Great community!

Comment: @RaveN You can accept his answer with the tickmark to the left of this answer. Please do so.

Answer (score 8):

#### Plain Javascript

This is how you iterate on the elements of an array, using a `for` loop ([do not use a `for...in` loop on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays), if you ever get tempted).

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.genres.length; i++) {
    console.log( results.genres[i].name );
}
```

Your array is called `results.genres` here. Inside the loop, `results.genres[i]` will always refer to the current element.

#### jQuery

I see that you are using jQuery, so you can also use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) like this:

```
$.each(results.genres, function (currentIndex, currentElem) {
    console.log( currentElem.name );
});
```

Comment: What is console.log? 
I will try getting further with this. Thanks!

Comment: @RaveN Not only programmers are able to use Google. `console.log()` prints values to the console of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can access array values by using a for-in loop like this:

```
var result = "";

for (i in genres.name) {
  result += genres.name[i];
} 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

***You can use***

```
<script>
   results = '{ "genres": [{ "id": 28, "name": "Action" },{ "id": 18, "name": "Drama" },{ "id": 14, "name": "Fantasy" },{ "id": 36, "name": "History" }] }';    
   results = JSON.parse(results);

       for($i in results.genres){
            console.log(results.genres[$i].name);
       }

</script>
```

**JSON.parse** method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing and you can get value from node like array.
When you use `for($i in results.genres)` you dont net set limite size, 'case for get all array/object elements.

**Group Elements** need are between **{** "genres": [{ ...}] **}** for your JSON'll be read.

Comment: when you call `results.genres[$i].name`  with `$i`, function get id Element starting in 0 inside this for. If you wanna get only first element set this `results.genres[0].name`.

Comment: Example JAVASCRIP https://jsfiddle.net/xtwqr937/ Example JQUERY https://jsfiddle.net/a7abb0bd/